# Get Current date in epoch from Unix shell script

Tags: unix, shell, epoch

How to get the current date value in epoch i.e., number of days elapsed since 1970-1-1. I need solution in unix shell script.

Comment: What language or technology are you using?

Comment: I'm using unix. I need this to use inside a shell script...

Comment: Today 14,432 days have passed since the epoch. ;) http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=1&d1=1&y1=1970&m2=&d2=&y2=

Comment: Are you sure you want the number of _days_ since epoch? The answers so far give you seconds :) you'll need to divide that by 60 * 60 * 24 to get your answer :)

Comment: Search for "days between two dates".

Comment: thanks to all... but my system is not recognizing the +%s format specifier, am not getting the result :(

Comment: What kind of system are you on, then? Anyway, give the solution I posted below a try. Perhaps that script is more portable...

Comment: Regarding @Stephan202's link, I find [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to be a richer source of information and tools than timeanddate.com.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Update**: The answer previously posted here linked to a custom script that is no longer available, solely because the OP indicated that `date +'%s'` didn't work for him. Please see [UberAlex' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094357/74939) and [cadrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094328/74939) for *proper* solutions. In short:

1. For the number of *seconds* since the Unix epoch use [`date(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) as follows:

   ```
   date +'%s'
   ```
2. For the number of *days* since the Unix epoch divide the result by the number of seconds in a day (mind the double parentheses!):

   ```
   echo $(($(date +%s) / 60 / 60 / 24))
   ```

Comment: This is not the best answer, and no longer useful at all, as the links are broken. It should be a one liner, as below.

Comment: @SamWatkins: Very much agreed. Unfortunately accepted answers cannot be deleted.

Comment: @alancnet: the answer was not incorrect for the OP, but he did have a very weird setup indeed. Anyway, I had enough of all the downvotes, so I rewrote the answer to something that is useful for the other 99.9999% of the planet.

Answer (score 176):

The Unix Date command will display in epoch time

the command is

```
date +"%s"
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/date

**Edit:** Some people have observed you asked for days, so it's the result of that command divided by 86,400

Comment: Note that `%s` is an extension. POSIX date does not have `%s`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html for details.

Comment: Not all days have 86400 seconds (DST, leap seconds, etc...)

Comment: Again, in unix time (date +%s) each day has 86400 "seconds", it does not include leap seconds and certainly not DST.  The answer is correct.

Comment: Is it possible to display the milliseconds since the epoch?

Comment: @DanielPendergast In Bash at least, `expr $(date +"%s") \* 1000`.

Comment: That won't give you the actuall millisecond current time though (which I'm looking for in my performance profiling).

Answer (score 12):

```
echo $(($(date +%s) / 60 / 60 / 24))
```

Comment: Note that `%s` is an extension. POSIX date does not have `%s`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html for details.

Comment: Not all days have 86400 (60*60*24) seconds (DST, leap seconds, etc...)

Comment: Unix time does have 86400 seconds per day exactly.
Note, if using with -d for a specific date, suggest -u for UTC,
or answer will vary by timezone.

echo $(( $(date -u -d '2014-01-01' +%s) / 86400 ))

Answer (score 2):

```
echo `date +%s`/86400 | bc
```

Comment: Not all days have 86400 seconds (DST, leap seconds, etc...)

Answer (score -3):

Depending on the language you're using it's going to be something simple like

```
CInt(CDate("1970-1-1") - CDate(Today()))
```

Ironically enough, yesterday was day 40,000 if you use 1/1/1900 as "day zero" like many computer systems use.

Comment: That looks like VB to me. The question asks in relation to a Unix shell script.

Comment: He edited it after I answered.  Thanks for your input anyway.