# Get seconds since epoch in any POSIX compliant shell

Tags: shell, scripting, time, posix

I'd like to know if there's a way to get the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch in any POSIX compliant shell, without resorting to non-POSIX languages like perl, or using non-POSIX extensions like GNU awk's strftime function.

Here are some solutions I've already ruled out...

> `date +%s` // Doesn't work on Solaris

I've seen some [shell scripts](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/shell/programs/time/) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094291/1094354#1094354) before, which parse the output of `date` then derive seconds from the formatted gregorian calendar date, but they don't seem to take details like leap seconds into account.

GNU awk has the `strftime` function, but this isn't available in standard `awk`.

I could write a small C program which calls the `time` function, but the binary would be specific to a particular architecture.

Is there a cross platform way to do this using only POSIX compliant tools?

I'm tempted to give up and accept a dependency on perl, which is at least widely deployed.

> perl -e 'print time' // Cheating (non-POSIX), but should work on most platforms

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a portable / `POSIX` solution:

```
PATH=`getconf PATH` awk 'BEGIN{srand();print srand()}'
```

Unlike a `C` compiler or `Perl`, `awk` is guaranteed to be present on a POSIX compliant environment.

How it works:

- ***PATH=`getconf PATH`*** is making sure the `POSIX` version of `awk` is called should it not be the first one in the `PATH`.
- Per the [`POSIX` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_12) :
  ***srand([expr])***
  Set the seed value for rand to expr or use the time of day if expr is omitted. The previous seed value shall be returned.

  The first call is omitting a parameter so the seed value is set to the time of day. The second call is returning that time of day, which is the number of seconds since the epoch.

  Note that with many `awk` implementations but not the GNU one (`gawk`), this first call is not required as the function already returns the expected value in the first place.

Comment: OK; I stand corrected.  Yes, I assumed `awk`'s `srand()` would parallel the C version.  It clearly doesn't.  Weird, but what you describe is what the POSIX docs for `awk` say should happen.

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu): the first `srand()` is necessary.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, answer updated to state gawk behavior.

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks for the great answer! Note: using `printf` rather than `print` will avoid the trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

Just for educational purposes, a bit of a hack. But it's as POSIX as you can imagine :-)

```
#!/bin/sh
: > x
echo "ibase=8;$(pax -wx cpio x | cut -c 48-59)" | bc
rm x
```

Lets see what this prints:

```
$ ./x.sh; date +%s
1314820066
1314820066
```

Comment: `pax -wx cpio x` produces `pax: Bad Option: -wx` and then usage info

Comment: `pax -wx cpio x` produces two lines:
`pax: cpio header field is too small to store file x` `0707070000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000001300000000000TRAILER!!!`. The same goes for `pax -w -x cpio x`. pax version: 1:20171021-2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score -4):

Should be fairly portable, but requires write access to `${.CURDIR};` perhaps it could be modified.

I didn't use `/tmp` for the executable since most people have `/tmp` mounted noexec.

Works on FreeBSD, anyway.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Portably gets the date since epoch

bn=`basename $0`
prog=`mktemp /tmp/${bn}.mktime.XXXXXXX` || exit 1
>${prog}.c cat <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {printf("%ju", time(NULL)); return 0; }
EOF

cc ${prog}.c
time=`./a.out`
rm ${prog} a.out

echo Time since epoch = $time seconds
```