# How to print the number of seconds since unix epoch in solaris shell

Tags: unix, date, solaris

Is there a way to use unix `date` to print the number of seconds since epoch?

I'm open to using other standard shell commands if there is a way

(I'm using Solaris, so there isn't `date "+"%s"`)

Thanks

Comment: Is perl (perl -e 'print localtime' ) not an acceptable answer?  I can't think of how to do it with the date command.

Comment: @MJB rather than 'print localtime', the comparable perl expression to "date +%s" would be "perl -e 'print time'"

Comment: probably should be considered a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445198/get-seconds-since-epoch-in-any-posix-compliant-shell (but there are many duplicates of this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since this is a programming site, I would just compile something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main (void) {
    printf ("%d\n",time(0));
    return 0;
}
```

:-)

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -e 'print time'
```

Comment: alias epoch="perl -e 'print time'"

Answer (score 0):

you can try nawk,(but try to double confirm with the perl commands and see if they give the same results)

```
nawk "BEGIN{print srand}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> /usr/bin/truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | grep ^time | awk '{print $3}'