# using date function in unix

Tags: epoch

1. how can I determine machine time in seconds on unix O/S? (i can't use 'date +%s', it's not POSIX).
2. what functions exist for date and epoch time in second?
3. by using date "+%format" how can i subtract 1-2 hour from present hour?

Regards

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445198

Answer (score 0):

Try [the `time` function in `time.h`](http://man.cx/time%282%29). For example:

```
time_t the_time=time(NULL);
// the_time now contains the number of seconds since the epoch
```

To get a time in the past, just subtract the number of seconds. Since there are 3600 seconds in an hour, to go an hour back, just subtract 3600.

Comment: it can be use in shell script? it recieve value?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using C. I don't see what's wrong with `date +%s`; I'm using Mac OS X and it works here.

Comment: A little searching shows that Solaris is a little odd in this respect. This may be helpful, but I'm not sure: http://solarisjedi.blogspot.com/2006/06/solaris-date-command-and-epoch-time.html

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to say: you may need to use platform detection. It sucks, but so does Solaris not supporting `date +%s`.